# How do I change the y-axis increment in Core Plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am specifying the y-range for my graph made in Core Plot in my iOS app with

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(yAxisStart)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(yAxisLength)];
```

How do I change how much each tick on the y-axis increments by? By default, Core Plot uses 0.5 I believe.

In general, where is systematic documentation for Core Plot? I couldn't find it in the Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the default axis labeling policy (fixed interval), change the `majorIntervalLength` to adjust the spacing between major ticks.

The documentation is available online at [Google Code](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html) and as an Xcode docset in the Core Plot package. There are two versions of the docs—one for iOS and another for Mac OS X. The two versions are very similar. Differences mostly relate to UIKit vs. AppKit issues and bindings on the Mac.